# How to use stargazer with estimateEffect() from STM? Receiving unrecognized object type error

Tags: r, stargazer

I have some regressions from the STM package that I hope to format using stargazer.

```
log.reg.black <- estimateEffect(c(18) ~ districtpctmale + districtpctwhite + college + poverty + factor(Candidate_Gender.x) + cook + factor(year) + factor(black.y), stmobj = all_model, metadata = data) 

stargazer(log.reg.black,
          omit.stat = c("adj.rsq", "rsq", "ser", "f"),
          omit.table.layout = "n",
          column.labels = c("Topic 18"),
          covariate.labels = c("District: Male", "District: White", "District: College", "District: Poverty", "Candidate Gender", "Cook Score", "Year: 2012", "Year:2014", "Candidate: Black"),
          dep.var.caption = "Topics",
          star.char = c(" ", "  ", "  "),
          digits = 2,
          dep.var.labels.include = F,
          title = "Estimating Effects of Topic Models (Interaction)",
          model.numbers = F)
```

However, when I run the code, I receive the error:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

I suspect it's because of the object type that estimateEffect() produces, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions how to use stargazer to format my regression table or other packages I could use? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: This post should provide you with an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300261/how-to-create-a-table-of-gravity-models-side-by-side-using-the-gravity-package/63319070?noredirect=1#comment111974595_63319070

Answer (score 0):

Stargazer only accepts certain regression models. You can see that list here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf